# Remove single quotes from specific string in php

Tags: php, string, replace

I have xml String which contains the following string in two places that I need to modify by removing the single quotes without effecting other parts having single quotes

```
Contact submitted the Form 'Register here-SOD75' . See details under WWW
```

and I want to remove the single quotes so it becomes:

```
Contact submitted the Form Register here-SOD75 . See details under WWW
```

The value inside the quotes varies.

How can I do that?

Comment: Please precise which language you are working with. Thanks

Comment: I have edited the subject i am working with php.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `str_replace` function.

```
$str = "Contact submitted the Form 'Register here-SOD75' . See details under WWW";    
$str = str_replace("'", "", $str);
echo $str; //Contact submitted the Form Register here-SOD75 . See details under WWW
```

Comment: The string is xml which is quite long and i don't want effect other parts. I want to pickup this string only and modify it.

Comment: It's quiet unclear to me. Please modify your question as per the exact requirement.

Comment: Do you `'` else where that you on't want to replace in the complete string?

Comment: I checked my xml string but i don't have single quote anywhere else i just $str = str_replace("'", "", $str); but i don't know why i didn't do anytihng.